# Error connecting to CRM Server

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to register  a plugIns in the CRM 2013 Online, But I got the below error :

```
Error connecting to CRM Server. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?
```

I tried to find out , what the reason for above error , but I failed, Could anyone help me to find out of reason of this error ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you see the service if you connect via a web browser? This could be related to your environment.  https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc

Comment: Yes, this is connected with Web browser, but whenever I tried to deploy (register) the PlugIns, it throw above error

Answer (score 0):

the address you are using can be wrong:

https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?

https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc
Microsoft Office 365
EMEA
https://dev.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc
Microsoft account
https://disco.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc
Microsoft Office 365
APAC
https://dev.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc
Microsoft account
https://disco.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc
Microsoft Office 365
South America
https://disco.crm2.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc

based on the location of the server you will have a different discovery service.